# Are CS-degree questions considered valid "career building" questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I was watching [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256140/most-appropriate-masters-degree) (just an example) and was wondering if it would be considered a valid question under "career building" from the Stack Overflow blog:

[A Question About Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/a-question-about-questions/)

> The current results for Which type of “programming related” questions are appropriate [on Stack Overflow]?, in order by votes, are:
>
> (1) - (6) [omitted]
>
> (7) Questions about social engineering, management, or **career building**, ergonomics, or other “soft” topics related to development work.
>
> "The “winners” of this poll, items 1-7, map strongly to my idea of what we built Stack Overflow for. Items 8-11 … not so much."

So, for my sense of what "belongs," what's the call on this type of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is career-building questions for programmers directly and definitely relate. However, that opinion appears to be a minority one.

Comment: That's why I want to build a consensus. The blog post is pretty clear that SO *is* supposed to welcome these types of questions but, I agree, that opinion/follow-through seems to be in the minority.